# Vue2 - attribute binding in components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have following component:

```
Vue.component('ordering-filters', {
    template: `
        <div class="arrow-group">
            <a href="#"
                :class="{'active' : isActive, 'fa fa-sort-asc fa-lg text-muted': true}"
                aria-hidden="true"
                @click="orderCountries({orderBy: orderBy, order: 'asc'})"                                   >
            </a>
            <a href="#"
                :class="{'active' : isActive, 'fa fa-sort-desc fa-lg text-muted': true}"
                aria-hidden="true"
                @click="orderCountries({orderBy: orderBy, order: 'desc'})">
            </a>
        </div>
    `,

    methods: {

        orderCountries(params){
            this.isActive = !this.isActive;
        }

    },

    data() {
        return {
            orderBy: '',
            isActive: false
        }
    }

});
```

How can I bind **orderBy** parameter to the HTML tag:

```
<td class="col-md-6">Country Name
    <ordering-filters></ordering-filters>
</td>
```

And how can I change **isActive** parameter for the clicked element (setting it to true, and setting it to false for the element which isn't clicked)?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are saying "how can I pass an `orderBy` value to the `ordering-filters` instance", then you are looking for [`props`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).

   props: {
   orderBy: {
   type: String,
   required: true
   }
   }

Then

```
<ordering-filters :order-by="someStringVal"></ordering-filters>
```

2. For your second question, you don't necessarily need `isActive`.

   <a href="#" :class="{'active' : order === 'asc'}"
   @click="orderCountries({orderBy, order: 'asc'})">
   <a href="#" :class="{'active' : order === 'desc'}"
   @click="orderCountries({orderBy, order: 'desc'})">

   methods: {
   orderCountries(params){
   this.order = params.order
   }
   }

Comment: I went in that direction at first but got following errors (the errors are the same with your example):
**[Vue warn]: Property or method "name" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

(found in <Root>)**

**[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "orderBy". Expected String, got Undefined.

found in

---> <OrderingFilters>
       <Root>**

I thought I was missing on something, or that I was going in the wrong direction. It is a bit hard to wrap my mind around Vue :/

Comment: @Sasha Judging from this comment, I suggest you to go through the introduction section of Vue docs. Because obviously you don't even know the basis of MVVM concept, e.g. what is a "binding".